# The color scheme shown is wrong in the viewer after translation of a zip file( containing .obj and .mat )

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have an obj file & a material file for it that defines the color scheme I require. When I zip these two and send it for translation and view the translated model in viewer I can see the colors are not the ones I am expecting. When I open this obj file in Meshlab I am able to see the colors correctly.

Snapshots from Meshlab. (#expected)[image]

Snapshots from Meshlab. (#expected)[image]

What I saw in Forge viewer after translation. (#Wrong result)[image]

(#Wrong result)[image]

(#Wrong result)[image]

Comment: can you share this obj/mat so we can investigate?

Comment: Found the problem.

(in .mat file I wrote color info as)
newmtl mat3
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.0
Killum 1here In line Kd 1.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.0 when I removed the comas color scheme started to work as expected.

Comment: I think you should add support to comas as well, cause I was able to see it correctly in Meshlab with comas. Thank You.

Comment: thanks for sharing it, if possible can you describe exactly how it was before and after? Maybe add an answer? then I can ask for improvement with my dev team. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are my .mat file contents(materials) that obj file uses.

```
newmtl mat0
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 0.3333333333333333 1.0 1.0
Killum 1
newmtl mat1
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.0 1.0 0.4980392156862745
Killum 1
newmtl mat2
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 0.3333333333333333 0.6666666666666666 1.0
Killum 1
newmtl mat3
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.0
Killum 1
newmtl mat4
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.0, 0.3333333333333333, 1.0
Killum 1
newmtl mat5
Ka 1.00 1.00 1.00
Kd 1.0, 0.0, 0.0
Killum 1
```

here In lines

```
Kd 1.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.0
&
Kd 1.0, 0.3333333333333333, 1.0
&
Kd 1.0, 0.0, 0.0
```

when I removed the comas color scheme started to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting it, we're now investigating it under `TREX-748` (internal code, for your reference)